# geoPlugin undefine variable with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

I have a few sites using [geoPlugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/) and after Microsoft's IE Update on 9/24/2012 I'm having some strange issues.  I first noticed that my nivo slider wasn't showing up on my homepage, so I dug into the console to find a

`SCRIPT5009: 'geoplugin_countryCode' is undefined`

I then debugged the same page in Google Chrome and everything is working fine there. I attempted to decipher the KB2744842 bulletin regarding that update

Here's my javascript:

```
<script src="https://ssl.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var country = geoplugin_countryCode();

        if(country === 'CA'){
            $('#notification').html('<div class="attention" style="display: none;">You are in Canada</div>');
            $('.attention').fadeIn('slow');
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        }else if(country != 'US'){
            $('#notification').html('<div class="attention" style="display: none;">You are in the USA</div>');
            $('.attention').fadeIn('slow');
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        }else{
            //nothing stupid IE
        }

    });
    $('.geoClose').live('click', function() {
        console.log('geoplugin notify closed');
        document.cookie = 'geoClose=true;'
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header Text</div>
  <div id="notification"></div>
  <div id="content">Content Here!</div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geoPlugin has recently changed some policies regarding SSL requests and apparently IE won't follow the redirect implemented while other browses will.

resulting code:

```
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/statistics.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="https://ssl.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var country = geoplugin_countryCode();

        if(country === 'CA'){
            $('#notification').html('<div class="attention" style="display: none;">You are in Canada</div>');
            $('.attention').fadeIn('slow');
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        }else if(country != 'US'){
            $('#notification').html('<div class="attention" style="display: none;">You are in the USA</div>');
            $('.attention').fadeIn('slow');
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        }else{
            //nothing stupid IE
        }

    });
    $('.geoClose').live('click', function() {
        console.log('geoplugin notify closed');
        document.cookie = 'geoClose=true;'
    });
//]]>
</script>
```